# How to combine groupby and sort values

Tags: pandas

How to merge two groupby and sort_values in to one

`df_most_ordered = online_rt.groupby(by=['Country']).sum()`

`df_most_ordered.sort_values(['Quantity'],ascending=False).iloc[1:11]`

Comment: As in, you want to write the command in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.` for chaining both rows to one:

```
online_rt.groupby(by=['Country']).sum().sort_values(['Quantity'],ascending=False).iloc[1:11]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [method chaining](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/method-chaining.html):

```
online_rt.groupby(by=["Country"]).sum().sort_values(
    ["Quantity"], ascending=False
).iloc[1:11]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the action in a same line by using the "."

```
df_most_ordered = online_rt.groupby(by=['Country']).sum().sort_values(['Quantity'],ascending=False).iloc[1:11]
```